# С какой буквы правильно писать слово договор в тексте письма?

Tags: орфография

Для проведения работ по пункту 1.3 технического задания к договору оказания услуг 2258/У от 13.12.2018, прошу направить информацию об используемой в компании...

Answer (score 1):

Если в тексте название (титул) договора и выходные данные соответствуют шапке самого документа, слово пишется с прописной. При пропущенных знаках (в вашем случае вероятен пропуск знака *№*) и перестановке слов — со строчной.